# How to check that a candidate is not joining on holiday and weekend

Tags: sql-server

I have one table HolidayList and another table JoiningDateList:

```
HolidayId   HolidayDate            CandidateId    JoiningDate  
1           2016-01-26                1            2016-01-26
2           2016-03-07                2            2016-02-12
3           2016-04-08                3            2016-04-08
                                      4            2016-06-06
```

What i want is if holiday date clashing with joiningDate it should skip that date and if the new date clashes with weekends then it should skip that as well.

Comment: What have you tried?  Could you give an example of expected output based on the sample data you've posted.  I suspect the downvote is due to a poorly written question.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is pretty easy to solve if you've created a Date Table.  This is simply a table that every date between a set of dates with information about that date, like day of week, and if it's a holiday.  See [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) for details on how to create and populate this table.  The only change I would make from what the blog post says would be to make the table key a "Date" data type and not in int.

Once you have the date table the solution would look something like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Users') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #Users

CREATE TABLE #Users(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, JoiningDate DATE NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #Users(id, JoiningDate)
     VALUES (1, '7/3/2016') -- weekend day before holiday
          , (2, '7/5/2016') -- good day
          , (3, '7/9/2016') -- weekend

SELECT u.id, u.JoiningDate, d.AdjustedDate
  FROM #Users u
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN([Date]) AS AdjustedDate
                      FROM dbo.Dates d
                     WHERE [Date] >= u.JoiningDate AND d.DayOfWeek BETWEEN 2 AND 6 AND d.Holiday = 0) d
```